# Solve $100n^2 = 2^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I don't understand how to solve this... I try to get rid of the $2^n$ via logarithms and it leads me to $2log_210 + 2log_2n = n$ and I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This looks like an implicit equation to me or to put it in other words there is no explicit solution for this problem.

Comment: To solve this "explicitly" you need the Lambert W function.  Numerically, the solutions are $n=0.1036578164, 14.32472784, -0.09670403432$

Comment: Any advice on what to study next so I can better identify these and/or solve them in the future?

Comment: I'd like to add that one can quickly see that no natural number $n$ solves the equation, since the left hand side then contains at least a couple of factors $5$, while the right hand side only contains factors $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Lambert W method: $y = xe^x$ if and only if $W(y) = x$.

For this problem:
$$
100 n^2 = 2^n
$$
take square-root,
$$
10 n = 2^{n/2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad 10 n = -2^{n/2}
$$
Lets do the first one
$$
10 n = 2^{n/2}
\\
10 n = \exp\left(\frac{n (\log 2)}{2}\right)
\\
\frac{1}{10 n} = \exp\left(\frac{-n (\log 2)}{2}\right)
\\
\frac{1}{10} = n\;\exp\left(\frac{-n (\log 2)}{2}\right)
\\
-\frac{\log 2}{20} = \frac{-n \log 2}{2}\exp\left(\frac{-n (\log 2)}{2}\right)
$$
All of that was to get it in the form $y = x e^x$.  Then go to $W(y) = x$:
$$
W\left(-\frac{\log 2}{20}\right) = \frac{-n (\log 2)}{2}
\\
-\frac{2}{\log 2}W\left(-\frac{\log 2}{20}\right) = n
$$

**Note.**  Students of high-school algebra are not expected to know the Lambert W funcion.  And they are not expected to be able to solve this problem explicitly.

Comment: Can you point me toward a math course or book that commonly covers this?

Comment: @Shane: I've never seen the Lambert W function in a book, but it is covered in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and in [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).